# Generic method replaces parametric type on the fly causing an exception

Tags: java, android, json, generics, type-conversion

I have the following unified method to convert [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)s into Java arrays. I admit it looks not so nice as it should be, but AFAICT this is the most Java generics can afford for this task.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] getArray(JSONArray array, Class<T> clazz)
{
  if(array == null) return null;
  int nfiles = array.length();
  if(nfiles == 0) return null;
  T result[] = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, nfiles);
  for(int j = 0; j < nfiles; j++)
  {
    try
    {
      T vv = (T)array.get(j);      // temp variable for investigation, type T
                                   // assigment passes without an exception!
      if(vv.getClass() != clazz)   // outputs "java.lang.Integer!=java.lang.Long"
      {
        LOG(vv.getClass().getName() + "!=" + clazz.getName());
      }
                                   // Next line throws ArrayStoreException
      result[j] = vv;              // Integer cannot be stored in an array of type Long[]
    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      result[j] = null;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

One can use it so (this is just an example, in the real code input arrays come from hierarchical JSON structures):

```
Integer a[] = getArray(new JSONArray("[15,16]"), Integer.class);
```

It seemed working ok for some time until I stumbled on an array which should be of type `Long`. The method fails with `ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer cannot be stored in an array of type java.lang.Long[]` on the line, which is marked accordingly in the code.

Well, I understand that `JSONArray.get()` method returns `Object`, which contains whatever type the JSON library considers appropriate for current input. And if it sees an array like this "[15,16]" it deduces the type as `Integer`. The problem is that the line with the temp variable should read after deparametrization:

```
Long vv = (Long)array.get(j);
```

and as far as the `get()` returns `Integer`, this is the line which should throw a type casting exception or convert the `Integer` instance to the `Long` instance, if it's safe, as I think. Instead of this, the type of the temp variable is dynamically changed to `Integer` which is confirmed by the log output, and only then the code breaks on attempt to store this `Integer` to the prepared array of `Long`s.

Actually I can workaround this easily by code like this:

```
if(clazz == Long.class)
{
  vv = array.getLong(j);
}
```

But this is exactly the reason why I wrote this method in the hope that generics can handle this for me: its purpose is to eliminate the need of many conditional checks for different types and calls to specific methods such as `getBoolean`, `getString`, etc.

Could someone explain me what's happening here and how to fix the code keeping it as simple and unified as possible?

<sup>BTW, I did not find a way how to write a long number as input literal for the `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` to be recognized as `Long`. For example, the input "[15L,16L]" produces Java array of `String`s ["15L", "16L"] after parsing by `JSONArray`. Am I missing something?</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The heart of  the issue is this line

```
T vv = (T) array.get(j);
```

This line is not using the `clazz` parameter, and contains an *unchecked cast* that produces a compilation warning. The *regular cast* is a virtual machine instruction that takes a Java class as input and check a Java object against it. When you use a type variable (`T` in this case) the JVM instruction is in fact a useless cast to `Object`, since no more information is available at compile time. The compiler emits a warning that the runtime type may in fact not be `T`, but you are ignoring it and it screws up at runtime with an `ArrayStoreException` (note that this would not even happen if you used a `List<E>` because the type parameter is not represented at runtime).

To solve your problem you absolutely need a series of `if` statements - it's not bad implementation, just environmental complexity that must be managed.

Comment: Thank you. Just to sum up (or rephrase). It looks like Java generics allow the same parametrized type T to be seemingly resolved as different type on different lines of code block, where T is assumed to be consistent, and this is because it's `Object` in fact. Right?

Comment: Not sure. Generics are a language feature with known scope and limits. Your use case goes beyond those limits, and the Java compiler doesn't block you (because the program could be right) but emits a warning because it cannot prove its type safety. You ignore the warning and get a runtime error

Comment: Lets forget the use case and warning and consider simple fact: there is a method with generic type T which is known to be `Long` at compile time (according to the method invocation line). How this T can be other than `Long` inside the method? The variable `T vv` got `Integer` type. From your answer, I thought that T is actually an Object (which makes me think that generics not so powerful and strict as C++ templates, that I accustomed to). But you are "not sure" about this. So I don't get it.

Comment: The fact I'm not sure about is your understanding of generics in Java :) It's mostly a compile-time feature. The compiler can't prove that array.get(i) returns a Long, and in fact you have to cast. Now, a Java cast translates to a JVM instruction, except that the construct (T) uses a type variable that doesn't exist at runtime and is replaced in the bytecode with its bound (Object). This cast is unchecked: you get a compiler warning, ignore it, and get a runtime error. TL;DR: yes, generics seem less powerful than what you think (I don't know C++ templates)